# the $elemMatch operator does not work correctly in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have the following collection

```
>db.prueba.find({})
{ "_id" : "A", "requi" : null }
{ "_id" : "D", "requi" : [ "A", "B" ] }
{ "_id" : "E", "requi" : [ "B" ] }
{ "_id" : "B", "requi" : null }
{ "_id" : "C", "requi" : [ "A" ] }
```

I need each element of the `requi field` to be in the following array. in this case, the array has only one element

```
['A']
```

When I use the operator `$elemMatch` returns the following

```
db.prueba.find({requi:{$elemMatch:{$in:['A']}}})
{ "_id" : "D", "requi" : [ "A", "B" ] }
{ "_id" : "C", "requi" : [ "A" ] }
```

the query must returns only document

```
{ "_id" : "C", "requi" : [ "A" ] }
```

please, help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`$eq`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) operator to find the exact match in the array

```
db.collection.find({ "requi": { "$eq": [ "A" ] } })
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": "C",
    "requi": [
      "A"
    ]
  }
]
```

Check it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mG6zS2WUmym)